# Edit existing friendly url

Tags: php, sql, url

I have in my sql table two columns. path and title.

path = basically create the friendly url from the title (example: welcome-to-the-jungle).

title = responsible for the titles (example: Welcome To The Jungle!).

My database table has grown and I wanted to optimize it. i wanted to use the title column as path And trim the unwanted characters (?!,.).

I have already function that trim the unwanted characters (worked for path column) "post_slug".

I could not get it to work with the function responsible for friendly url.
here is the real function, friendly url doesn't work, only with spaces (http://www.url.com/Welcome%20To%20The%20Jungle!).

```
Function get_single_article($title) {
    global $db, $prefix;

    $get_article = $db->query("SELECT *, a.id AS id, a.url AS url, s.url AS source_url FROM ".$prefix."articles a LEFT JOIN ".$prefix."sources s ON s.id = source_id WHERE title='$title'");
    $article = $db->fetch_array($get_article);

    $article[posted_on] = $this->relative_date($article[timestamp]);
    $article[description] = $this->word_split($article[description], 1000);
    return $article;
}
```

Here is what i tried: (http://www.url.com/welcome-to-the-jungle)

```
Function get_single_article($title) {
    global $db, $prefix;

    $newtitle = post_slug($title);
    $get_article = $db->query("SELECT *, a.id AS id, a.url AS url, s.url AS source_url FROM ".$prefix."articles a LEFT JOIN ".$prefix."sources s ON s.id = source_id WHERE title='$newtitle'");
    $article = $db->fetch_array($get_article);

    $article[posted_on] = $this->relative_date($article[timestamp]);
    $article[description] = $this->word_split($article[description], 1000);
    return $article;
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: If you're looking for optimization, using a title to identify your articles is not the way to go. The “slug” approach (your `path`) was probably better. For more optimization, try indexing it in your database. Also, you're missing quotes aroud your array keys (as in `$article[posted_on]` becomes `$article['posted_on']`)

Comment: my database have over 100,000 articles. if i will remove the path column its can significantly ease the size of my database. this is the still wrong way to ease the database size?

Comment: That depends on your vision of performance. The size would be reduced, but the query time will increase significally when you lookup an article using a non-indexed column. Read [this chapter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) from the MySQL doc for more insights on the subject

Comment: okay thank you. maybe there is another way i can reduce my database size without delete the path column? compression maybe?

Comment: Once again, you might loose performance in exec time (i'd say even more than without an index, but can't really say for sure) when fetching an article since you'll need to decompress the body (for instance) everytime you'll display a page. Optimizing the data structure may help you shrink it a bit (i'll let you google that), but keep in mind that the job of your db is to store your data, and there's no magic way to store 100,000 articles without using disk space